# Can't change value of nodes with same name

Tags: xml, powershell

Here is my XML file example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sc>
    <fluxs>
        <flux>
            <cible>
                <id>0</id>
            </cible>
        </flux>
        <flux>
            <cible>
                <id>1</id>
            </cible>
        </flux>
        <flux>
            <cible>
                <id>2</id>
                <wsdl_url>a</wsdl_url>
                <wsdl_url>b</wsdl_url>
            </cible>
        </flux>
    </fluxs>
</sc>
```

I want to change the value of nodes "wsdl_url"

I tried this :

```
$xml = [xml](get-content "c:\mme.xml")

# This works
write-host "Before" $xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.id
$xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.id = "Other"
write-host "After" $xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.id

# This does not work
write-host "Before" $xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.wsdl_url[0]
$xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.wsdl_url[0] = "AA"
write-host "After" $xml.sc.fluxs.flux[2].cible.wsdl_url[0]
```

In the first part, after having change que value of the id node, I get the new value ("Other").
In the second part, nothing change. Whats's wrong ?

Comment: If you want to update just the first value of that node you could do `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//wsdl_url').'#text' = 'newvalue'`

Comment: Hi, no, I need to change all the items. And unfortunately, I can't change the XML structure.

Comment: I think the problem is around tags with the same name. But I don't see how to solve it.

Comment: In that case you could use `$xml.SelectNodes('//wsdl_url').'` and then use a loop. What are you looking the new values to be? So far you're showing you want to edit the first with `AA`, what about the rest?

Comment: I showed you just the first occurence, 'cause I have already the problem with the first one : I can't change its value. But of course, my final purpose is to change all this nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, you can use [`SelectNodes` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-7.0) to get all `wsdl_url` nodes and from there is up to you what values would you like to use for each one of them. i.e. the below updates both existing nodes by index:

```bash
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//cible/wsdl_url')
$nodes[0].'#text' = 'hello'
$nodes[1].'#text' = 'world'
$xml.Save('path\to\new.xml')
```

Then the updated XML would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sc>
  <fluxs>
    <flux>
      <cible>
        <id>0</id>
      </cible>
    </flux>
    <flux>
      <cible>
        <id>1</id>
      </cible>
    </flux>
    <flux>
      <cible>
        <id>2</id>
        <wsdl_url>hello</wsdl_url>
        <wsdl_url>world</wsdl_url>
      </cible>
    </flux>
  </fluxs>
</sc>
```

Comment: @MarcM. glad it helped, please consider accepting it if answered your question